# How can I download the current DOM with HTML or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-6

I've created an HTML file that I later on modify using JavaScript by the click of a button. The button basically changes the content of a div when pressed.

Now, I added a button in the newly created content in that div, and I want it to prompt the "SaveAs" window (ctrl + s) or simply download it.

I'm restricted from using any framework or library like jquery. 
Has to be pure html or javascript.

To be clear: the "download" attribute in `<a>` downloads the original DOM which is not good for me.

Comment: You've clearly mistaken Stack Overflow for a code request site.  You have to at least attempt this yourself, so show us what you've already tried.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I'm in the army which has its own network and can't take the code out of their computer. The only solution I've found is the <a> element with the "download" attribute. I've done research beforehand and people said that javascript can't access the file system for security reasons. All I wanted to know is the way to perform a "ctrl + s" on the current page through code. I've been trying to find a solution for 3 days when I finally posted here. I can't show the code and if that means I can't get help, I'll try elsewhere. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You don't have to post the code of your current project. You can write some sample code on solutions you tried without influencing the integrity of your project.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript `document.documentElement` returns all elements in the root element. Just doesn't add html tags or doctype declerations.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Haha</title>
    <script>
        function test(){console.log("<html>" + document.documentElement + "</html>")}
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="test()">
    <div><p>Hi!</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```